# load angular components style latest

Tags: css, angular, primeng

how can I control the order of loading components css?
I know that in angular.json file the file that will be latest will override the others. there I import my primeng css
but the components css are generatered by angular.
how can I make it override the primeng css?
currently I have to add !important for all my style

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your component has ViewEncapsulation.None, his .css is applied to all the aplication and override the rest of .css. If you want override some .css of **all your primeng compoents**  you can add the .css in your main.app.component.css (really in any component  of your application) with viewEncapsulation.None

Comment: I don't want to disable ViewEncapsulation. What I wanted to know was how to make my component css to override others style/ currently I have to put !important and it is not a good idea